# WMS Layer for Solar Terminator

Tags: spotfire, wms

I am having a map chart in Spotfire and I am trying to add an Overlay for the solar terminator (day-night boundary - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(solar)).

I can't seem to locate any public WMS providers out there who offer that layer. Anybody know of any?

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleague helped me with the answer:
This layer is provided by the Space Science and Engineering Center (SSEC). It is available as a WMS or TMS here: https://realearth.ssec.wisc.edu/products/DayNight